# WPF application needs to detect numbers in browsers and MS excel

Tags: c#, wpf, google-chrome

I have a WPF application which makes phone calls. I need the application to detect phone numbers on web pages eg chrome, IE, firefox, MS Excel and give an option to dial them using the application if clicked. How do i make this happen ?

Any help is appreciated !

Answer (score 0):

i think that you could program a addon for chrome, IE , firefox, excel or any program and since there call to other application which use your service to call